# How to calculate % difference of row items in Julia array succinctly

Tags: julia

Given:

```
C = reshape([1.0, 2.0,1.1, 2.2, 1.2, 2.3],2,3)'
```

this gives me the following 3 x 2 array:

```
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
1.0  2.0
1.1  2.2
1.2  2.3
```

What I want to do is iterate through the rows and get the % difference between items.  So for each row `r` calculate (r-th+1 / r-th) - 1 and then return the results with the new first row all zeros. (ex. Col1 would be (1.1/1.0)-1 then (1.2/1.1)-1 and then the same pattern in Col2)

I'm trying to do it with the following for comprehension:

```
[zeros(length(C[1,:]),1);[(C[i+1,:] ./ C[i,:]) - 1 for i=1:length(C[:,1])-1]]
```

and what I expect to get is:

```
3×1 Array{Float64,2}:
[0.0,0.0]
[0.1,0.1]            
[0.0909091,0.0454545]
```

but what I get is:

```
4×1 Array{Any,2}:                   
0.0                   
0.0                   
[0.1,0.1]            
[0.0909091,0.0454545]
```

1. How can I get my first row of zeros to match up (and therefore get the type of the Array to correctly be Float64)?

...or even better...

2. Is there a less clunky way of pulling N-1 one rows out of an array and then tacking on a row of zeros (is there a more canonical Julia way of doing this)?

Comment: How about `[C[j,:] ./ C[i,:] - 1 for (i,j) in zip([1,1:size(C,1)-1...], 1:size(C,1))]`?

Comment: It can be even faster if the calculation is done in-place, overwriting the original values. This can work without allocations at all which take most of the time (actually benchmarked it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main advantages of Julia is that you don't need to write vectorized code, when a loop is clear and simple:

```julia
C = [1.0 2.0;
     1.1 2.2; 
     1.2 2.3;]

function row_diff(a)
    b = similar(a)
    b[1,:] = 0
    for i in 2:size(a,1)
         b[i,:] = a[i,:] ./ a[i-1,:] - 1
    end
    return b
end
```

Output:

```julia
julia> row_diff(C)
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
0.0        0.0      
0.1        0.1      
0.0909091  0.0454545
```

In fact, pure loops in Julia are often faster, because you can avoid intermediate copies and maintain cache locality (Julia arrays have column major order):

```julia
function row_diff_fast(a)
    b = similar(a)
    for j in 1:size(a,2)
        b[1, j] = 0
        for i in 2:size(a,1)
            b[i,j] = a[i,j] / a[i-1,j] - 1
        end
    end
    return b
end
```

**Edit:**

If you really want a one-liner (which is slow compared to the direct loop above):

```julia
[zeros(1,size(C,2));diff(C,1)./C[1:end-1,:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a one-liner comprehension:

```
[zeros(1, size(C, 2)) ; [C[i+1, j]/C[i, j]-1 for i in 1:size(C, 1)-1, j in indices(C, 2)]]
```

The performance should be similar to that of a loop.

Comment: The performance is only similar to that of my first loop, mainly because `vcat` makes a copy but also because of the overhead of comprehensions.  The overhead seems to be especially large for small matrices. For `C` from above, the difference is `412.654 ns` vs `37.214 ns` on my PC with Julia 0.5.

Comment: There is indeed an extra allocation. That there is an overhead to comprehensions vs loops, on the other hand, was a complete surprise to me.