# Dropping indices with Julia non-standard arrays

Tags: indexing, julia

In an answer I wrote previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41966459/2749865 I tried to make the code general enough to handle arrays with non-standard indexing. To that end used the construct `indices` in place of `1:size(...)`:

```
[C[i+1, j]/C[i, j]-1 for i in 1:size(C, 1)-1, j in indices(C, 2)]
```

As you can see, though, I could not figure out how to use `indices` when I want to drop the last element.

I can skip the *first* `n` elements by writing `drop(indices(C, 1), n)`, but cannot find any way to drop the *last* n indices.

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:** Just to head this one off. In my specific example I could have written

```
[C[i, j]/C[i-1, j]-1 for i in drop(indices(C, 1), 1), j in indices(C, 2)]
```

but I'm still interested in hearing if there is a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
[C[i+1, j]/C[i, j]-1 for i in indices(C, 1)[1:end-1], j in indices(C, 2)]
```

In other cases I've used constructs like

```
inds_interior = map(r->first(r)+1:last(r)-1, indices(A))
```

to skip the first and last element of each dimension.

Comment: This is giving similar performance to the ordinary `1:size(...)`:)  Do you think this pattern is common enough, now that supporting non-standard arrays is [encouraged](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/offset-arrays/), that it deserves its own idiom, e.g. `chop` (as @DanGetz suggested)? I certainly do stuff like this all the time in my code.

Comment: You'd want `chopfront` and `chopback`. I could be convinced otherwise, but current I don't see any particular advantage over `ind[1:end-3]`. In particular, at the moment indices have to be `AbstractVector`s or `AbstractArray`s, so all valid indices support that kind of operation.

Comment: There is already `drop`, so I was thinking `chop` would be a companion to that. Using `1:end-1` is an agreeable solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Iterators package:

```
using Iterators

for i in imap(first,partition(indices(C,1),n+1,1))
  @show i
end
```

does the trick. Specifically `partition` takes seqeunces of length `n+1` and `first` takes only the first element, and the last `n+1` sequence up to the end of the indices has the first element `n` elements before the last.

But perhaps a function would make things look better:

```
Base.chop(itr,n) = imap(first,partition(itr,n+1,1))
```

and now:

```
julia> chop(1:10,3)|>collect
7-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
```

`chop` is already defined for strings, removing the last character. It seems the semantics are so close to make overloading it appropriate.

Comment: This works, but I am seeing pretty horrendous performance. Replacing `1:size(C, 1)-1` with `chop(indices(C, 1), 1)` makes the code 3 orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: But it works for *any* iterator. To get better performance for `range` and iterators of known length, a better method is to `take` the right amount of values (`length()-n`). This would require a modification or another overload of `chop` which would better be done on a laptop and not on my phone.

Comment: Note that, according to the [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/offset-arrays/#writing-custom-array-types-with-non-1-indexing), non-standard arrays may not have `length` or `size` methods. (BTW, props for typing out programming advice on the phone!)